# WLAN not working on Fedora22, Broadcom BCM4352

Tags: fedora, broadcom, wlan

I've seen this quite a bit on some forums, none of the presented solutions have worked for me.
Here are the outputs for running the following commands in terminal:

```
$ uname -r 
4.1.7-200.fc22.x86_64

$ lspci |grep Broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

$ rpm -qa |grep -- -wl
broadcom-wl-6.30.223.248-2.fc22.noarch
kmod-wl-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64-6.30.223.248-8.fc22.1.x86_64
akmod-wl-6.30.223.248-9.fc22.x86_64
kmod-wl-6.30.223.248-8.fc22.1.x86_64
kmod-wl-4.1.7-200.fc22.x86_64-6.30.223.248-9.fc22.x86_64
```

It seems to me that kmod is installed properly, however when I do this:

```
$ akmods --force
Checking kmods exist for 4.1.7-200.fc22.x86_64             [  OK  ]
```

Nothing else happens - as far as I'm aware it's supposed to trigger some kind of installation process (that might be something entirely different though, I'm very new to Linux).
Also, this is what it prints when I search for my adapter manually:

```
$ lshw -C network
  *-usb:0                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11 n WLAN
       vendor: Ralink
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlp0s20u1
       version: 1.01
       serial: 1.0
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.1.7-200.fc22.x86_64 firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.1.45 link=yes maxpower=450mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:04:76:48
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Top one is my USB wlan adapter, middle one is the built in one I'd like to get running. Not sure about the last one.

USB wlan adapters are recognized immediatly upon plugging them in, so the hardware not working seems to be a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wireless card if it is a Boradcom you have to install vendor driver to get proper connection

First you have to verify your wireless card is Broadcom. So run this command as super user.

```
lspci | grep -i broadcom
```

Expected outcome something like

```
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```